Please help me with this master m3u8 url with a long looking key to download a video
below is the video link and master m3u8 link obtained from dev tools inspect. It has got a ck and looks like the key

however when i use hlsdl to download this mater.m3u8 url with the long key it complains saying that the key has to be 32 bytes long in aes.
some more screenshots from dev tools



